# Why is C++ returning the original value

Tags: c++

I am super new to programing in general let alone C++. Can anyone tell me why my program is also returning the original variable value?

```
int whichNumber(int x); //prototype

int main() {

    int x;


    cout << "Enter a number in the range 1-5: ";
    cin >> x; 
    int whichNumber(int x);
    cout << "\n" << whichNumber(x) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

//Functions
int whichNumber(int x){

    string numbers[] = {"one.", "two.", "three.", "four.", "five."};

    if(x == 1)
    cout <<"You entered the number " << numbers[0];
    else if(x == 2)
    cout << "You entered the number " << numbers[1];
    else if(x == 3)
    cout << "You entered the number " << numbers[2];
    else if(x == 4)
    cout << "You entered the number " << numbers[3];
    else if(x == 5)
    cout << "You entered the number " << numbers[4];
    else 
        cout << "Please enter a valid number.";

    return x;
}
```

If I don't put the "return x;" at the end of my function it returns 32766, which I think is the max space in an array. Just knowing why would help a lot. Although I would like it not to return the original value.

Thank you all for your time. I apologize if this has been answered, I haven't found it in the database.

I know the array probably isn't the best way to print words...but I don't know any other way. Still REALLY new to programming, I knew how to do it with an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I realize where the confusion is,

when you call `whichNumber(x)`, by virtue of that function having print statements in it, the call is sufficient to makethose statements appear on *stdout*. You don't need to wrap the call within a `cout`

Now let's fix your `whichNumber` function,. Your if ladder is kinda convoluted and there is a better way to do this. Your use of the array is actually *okay*.

```
int whichNumber(int x) {
    string numbers[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
    if ((x > 5) || (x < 1)) {
        cout << "Enter a valid number\n";
        return 1;  // returning 1 when a function fails is fairly common, though IMO in C++ I'd rather raise an exception
    }
    cout << "You entered " << numbers[x-1] << endl; // array indices start from 0
    return 0;
}
```

and in `main` turn this

```
int whichNumber(int x);
cout << "\n" << whichNumber(x) << "\n";
```

to this

```
int whichNumber(int x);
int s_code = whichNumber(x); // s_code has the success code of the func
```

as others have suggested if you don't want to deal with error codes you could just have the return type be `void` for the `whichNumber` function

Also, when you just don't `return` anything in a function that has a return type that is not `void`, it is up to the compiler how to handle this. This is called *undefined behavior*. This is a bad thing and you should try to avoid it.

welcome to C++, do check out the books in the first comment on your question :)

Comment: Thank all so much. I think I would have been stuck forever. @Srini I changed the "  int whichNumber(int x);
    cout << "\n" << whichNumber(x) << "\n";     "           to just "whichNumber(x)"  and it fixed the issue. The if...else are part of the assignment or I would totally use the condition...in fact I am making two versions. My crap that I have to turn in and the correct way.

Comment: I was re-calling the fuction.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to return a value, make the function a `void` return type.

```
void whichNumber(int x)
{
   // do stuff...
   return;  ///< optional, void doesn't return anything
}
```

It is returning `int x` because that is exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question - more of a comment than an answer really.

Answer (score 0):

x is the variable which contains the number you passed to the function, and you are returning the same x again.
In the function header, make return datatype as void and remove the return statement.